# How to destructure a json object into another json object?

Tags: json, reactjs, redux

My project uses React with Redux. In one of my components, I am getting some data from an API. It looks something like this,

```
{
"refresh": "some token",
"access": "some token",
"isStudent": true,
"user": {
    "username": "xyz",
    "first_name": "xyz",
    "last_name": "xyz",
    "email": "some email id",
    "groups": [
        2
    ],
    "id": 11
   }
}
```

The action for this looks like,

```
function login(data) {
 return {
  type: 'LOGIN',
  access: data.access,
  refresh: data.refresh,
  isStudent: data.isStudent,
  username: '',
  first_name: '',
  last_name: '',
  email: '',
 };
}
```

The exact json format fetched from the API is passed into `data` of the action,
The Redux State has a format like,

```
 const state = {
  isLogged: false,
  jwt: '',
  refresh: '',
  isStudent: true,
  username: '',
  email: '',
  first_name: '',
  last_name: '',
 };
```

Can I destructore the `data` in my action function?
Something like this,

```
function login(data) {
 return {
 type: 'LOGIN',
 access: data.access,
 refresh: data.refresh,
 isStudent: data.isStudent,
 {username,first_name,last_name,email}:data.user,
 };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't destructure directly into your return object the way you're thinking. But you can destructure nested data outside of your object and take advantage of object property shorthand:

```
function login(data) {
  const { access, refresh, isStudent, user: {
    username, first_name, last_name, email
  } } = data;

  return {
    type: 'LOGIN',
    access,
    refresh,
    isStudent,
    username,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    email
  };
}
```